# Database prototype Postgresql: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "messages"

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I am trying to set up a prototype database, and I am having trouble with one of my weak entities, `attachments` that keep returning the following error upon creation:

*ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "messages"*

The following shows the SQL create table statements (which is part of a large schema file with many more included).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Patients(
CPR_number integer NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20),
zip_code integer,
address varchar(100),
country varchar(20),
history text,
PRIMARY KEY (CPR_number)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages(
CPR_number integer,
topic text,
body text,
date_send varchar(8),
date_read varchar(8),
PRIMARY KEY (body, date_send),
FOREIGN KEY (CPR_number) REFERENCES Patients(CPR_number)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Attachments(
CPR_number integer,
file text,
body text,
date_send varchar(8),
PRIMARY KEY (file),
FOREIGN KEY (body) REFERENCES Messages(body),
FOREIGN KEY (date_send) REFERENCES Messages(date_send),
FOREIGN KEY (CPR_number) REFERENCES Patients(CPR_number)
);
```

Can anyone help me as to why I keep getting the error shown above? Originally I tried to have `date` attributes set as a `TIMESTAMP`, but it made sense why this could be somewhat hard to partition into weak entity sets which is why I changed it into `varchar(8)` (for MM-DD-YYYY representation). But I do not get why the above does not compile correctly.

I have several other weak entity sets, which the same structure, but where the creation completes successfully every time without any errors thrown. And I cant simply understand why the above should not work also. `messages` has the keys: `body`, `date_send` and `CPR_number` but somehow they are not matched?

Can anyone see what could be wrong?

Comment: A foreign key must reference **all** columns of the primary key.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `PRIMARY KEY (body, date_send)` makes no sense to me. And you will quickly run into problems if the body exceeds 3K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign keys should be to *primary* keys.  Your data model doesn't actually make sense.  I would expect something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Patients (
    patient_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    . . .
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages (
    message_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    patient_id int,
    . . .
    topic text,
    body text,
    date_send date,
    date_read date,
    foreign key (patient_id) REFERENCES Patients( patient_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Attachments (
    attachment_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    message_id int,
    file text,
    foreign key (message_id) references messages(message_id)
);
```

Note:  I have no idea what `cpr_number` is supposed to be.  Perhaps it is an attribute that should be in one of the table (a unique id for patients, perhaps?).  In any case, use synthetic primary keys and reference them.

Keep other things in mind:

- Dates should be stored as dates, not strings.
- Foreign keys should reference primary keys.
- Don't repeat data fields in multiple tables.  Values should be stored only once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I am still very new to SQL and databases in general, and I am just practicing skills from a course I am taking - so all feedback is good feedback. I can see the idea of just having a message_id instead as what I already intended. The schema I produced so far, have been over an already existing model, where they used a set of keys `body` + `date_send` to represent the `PRIMARY KEY` for the message table.